# RxJava: chain two flatmaps

Tags: rx-java2

I have a method `getListFromDatabase()` that returns `Single<List<User>> users`, and what I want to do:

```
getListFromDatabase()
.flatMap(// send list to another server)
.flatMap(// check if there are users that I have to added manually from a bundle, here I needs database connexion so I have to do this asynchronously, and I need the list I just retrieved)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(// handle onSuccess, onError etc.)
```

But in the first flatMap, it keeps telling me `missing return statement`. I didn't figure out what is the right syntax ?

Comment: Please, write the code you actually wanna use instead of the comments and I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
getListFromDatabase()
.flatMap(users -> sendAnotherService().map(ingoreResult -> users))
.flatMap(// check if there are users that I have to added manually from a bundle, here I needs database connexion so I have to do this asynchronously, and I need the list I just retrieved)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(// handle onSuccess, onError etc.)
```

where sendAnotherService() return Single with any type arg.